# Multiplication log normal and logarithmic function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, lognormal-distribution

Assume that $w$ follows a lognormal distribution $f(x)$. Given $a>0$, can the function:
$$
\int_ {x_0}^\infty \log(1+a\cdot x)\cdot f(x)\cdot dx 
$$
be written in a closed form?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Philippe. I took the liberty of editing your question to add $\LaTeX$ to enhance readability. Please make sure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: I can't see any way to do this, short of a power series involving incomplete gamma functions or something equally unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe just possible you can get somewhere with an integral involving Lambert's $W$ function; integrals involving Lambert functions seem to 'solve' a number of problems that look a little like this. I haven't played with them enough to do more than guess that it might be possible to make some progress that way.

If you actually want a numeric value for the integral (i.e. if $x_0, a, \mu$ and $\sigma$ are all known), I'd probably transform it to a normal and use a form of Gauss-Hermite quadrature.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature

Failing that, I'd be looking as some kind of expansion or series approximation.